# Ajax HTMLEditor - Copy, Paste buttons not appearing in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: asp.net, html-editor

I'm using an Ajax HTMLEditor in my application. When the page is accessed via FF and Chrome, the Copy and paste buttons on the tool bar are not visible though everthing looks good in IE9 and IE8.

In FF and Chrome, the css property display is set to 'none' by default but not in IE . I tried change the value css property - display to"block" and now though the buttons are visible , the functionality is not working.

You can see the same issue in the below link as well

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and Safari have issues with HTML Editors being created inside of tags with "display:none;" The solution is to not create the HTML editor until the tags that contain it are visible.